# jQuery UI Modal Popup Window - Button Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, modal-dialog, window

I' m trying to have my register button in a form lead in a modal window which will show the input of user's info. I have 3 problems so far.

1. After closing the modal window, my form is missing
2. I want to rename the "close" button of the modal window to "confirm" if possible
3. After closing (confirm) the modal window, i want to go back to the web page and the form to be empty (without the previous input)

My code so far:

HTML - Form :

```
<div id="myForm">
    <form name="myForm" method="POST">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Register your interest</legend>
            <div id="divpopup">
            <p><label class="title" for="name">Your name:</label>
                <input type="text" name="name" id="name"><br />
                <label class="title" for="email">Your email:</label>
                <input type="text" name="email" id="email"></p>
                <label class="title" for="persons">Persons:</label>
                <input id="personsId" type="text" name="persons" id="persons"></p>
            <p><label for="location" class="title">Your closest center:</label>
                <select class="target" name="location" id="location">
                     <option value="ny">New York</option>
                     <option value="il">Chicago</option>
                     <option value="ca">San Francisco</option>
                </select></p>
            <span class="title">Are you a member?</span>
            <label><input type="radio" name="member" value="yes" /> Yes</label>
            <label><input type="radio" name="member" value="no" /> No</label></p>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    <div class="submit" id="myButton"><input type="button" id="btnclick" value="Register" /></div>
    </form>
    <div class="quantity"></div>
    </div>
```

SCRIPT - Modal Window :

```
<script type="text/javascript"> //register modal window
    $(function() {
        $("#btnclick").click(function() {
            $("#divpopup").dialog({
                title: "Your Input",
                width: 500,
                height: 500,
                modal: true,
                buttons: {
                    Close:
                    function() {
                        $(this).dialog('close');
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    })
</script>
```

Comment: Rename to confirm done! 2 more to go!

Comment: the reason your form disappears is because you've included ur form code inside the popup div. try this http://jsfiddle.net/03srkck1/1/

Comment: did it work for you?

Comment: it keeps my form, but modal window doesnt give me the form..its empty

Comment: yeah. it wont. you need to write the logic for that. you just want to display the inputs that the user has entered so you can just create another div inside the popup div and when you click the register button, populate the values inside the popup div and it will work.

Comment: didn't quite get it but i ll keep searching..thx!

Comment: try this http://jsfiddle.net/03srkck1/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is clone the form into the dialog. Once they confirm, reset the original form. Something like this:

```
 $("#btnclick").click(function() {
    var dial = $("#myForm").clone();
    dial.dialog({
        modal: true,
        draggable: false,
        resizable: false,
        position: ['center', 'top'],
        show: 'blind',
        hide: 'blind',
        width: 400,
        dialogClass: 'ui-dialog-osx',
        buttons: {
            "Confirm": function() {
                $("#myForm").find("input").val("");
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jessikwa/p5L20rxb/1/